# calculating complexity of sorting

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

std::sort performs approximately N*log2(N) (where N is distance) comparisons of elements(source - http://www.cplusplus.com/),  so its complexity is N*log2(N).
Please, help me to calculate complexity for the next code:

```
void func(std::vector<float> & Storage)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size() - 1; ++i) 
   {
       std::sort(Storage.begin()+i, Storage.end());
       Storage[i+1] += Storage[i];
   }
}
```

complexity = N^2*log2(N) or 2log2(2)+3log2(3)+...+(N)log2(N)?
Thank you.

Comment: “N is distance” – it isn’t. What do you mean by that? What distance?

Comment: It depends on what the complexity of `std::sort` is for the pathological case where the data is already sorted.

Comment: For example, std::sort(Storage.begin(), Storage.end()); distance = Storage.end() -  Storage.begin() = Storage.size();

Comment: Why your algorithm is using std::sort for finding new place for element [i+1] instead of std::lower_bound?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to compute the complexity is to evaluate the complexity of repeated `O(K Log K)` problems of linearly increasing sizes `K = 1 ... N`. This can be done either by computing the sum, or by just computing the integral

```
Integrate[K Log[K], {K, 0, N}]
```

with e.g. Mathematica, and you get

```
1/4 N^2 (-1 + 2 Log[N])
```

which is of `O(N^2 Log N)`.

Even though for polynomial and logarithmic functions it holds true, in general it is not true that the integral of `K = 1 ... N` subproblems of complexity `f(K)` is equal to `N f(N)`. E.g. the sum of `K = 1 ... N` subproblems of complexity `Exp[K]` is simply `Exp[N]`, not `N Exp[N]`.

Comment: Thank you.
I have the next question about calculation of complexity.
The complexity of algorithm "A" is O(log N). 
If argument is increased from N to 1000*N (1000 times) - how many times the complexity is increased?

If O(N^2) - it is easy to calculate -> O(1000*N)/O(N) = (1000 * N)^2/N^2=1000^2 = 1000000;
But if comlexity is O(log N), there is a problem -> O(1000*N)/O(N) = log(1000N)/log(N) = ???

Comment: @TheNozza yes, for `O(log N)` any multiple of `N` is an N-dependent factor more expensive. In the limit of `N` goes to infinity, it is a factor of 1 in fact. But you can compute this: an algorithm of `O(log N)` only takes a factor of `K` more time for `N^K` more elements. So if K=2, and N=1000, it takes only twices as much time to do 1 million elements as it does to do 1 thousand.

Answer (score 0):

You are summing up logarithmic functions:

```
complexity <- 0

for i = 1..N
 complexity += i Log(i)
```

Resulting in the summation:

```
Log(1) + 2 Log(2) + ... + N Log(N)
```

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm:

> the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms of the factors:

thus:

the summation becomes:

```
Log(1) + Log(2^2) + .. + Log(N^N)
```

further simplifying:

```
Log(1*2^2*3^3*...*N^N)
```

Comment: you can use integrals instead of the sum to get my answer of `O(N^2 Log N)`. The sum will converge to that complexity for large `N`.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with `N^2*log2(N)` as the sort algorithm is run N times. In Big-O, where `c` is a constant:

```
c*N * N*log2(N) => O(N^2*log2(N))
```

Comment: std::sort algorithm runs N-1 times, where N - storage.size(). First time it sorts N elements, second time - N-1 elements, ..., at end it sorts last 2 elements in vector. Number of elements, which algorithm sorts, changes every cycle step. This is the main difficulty.

Comment: But asymptotically you can actually call that a constant times N, because no matter how slow or fast the limit varies (as you explained) it will be go over linear time. Therefor, simply discard the constant and say your using e.g. big-o.

Answer (score 0):

It will be asymptotically O((N^2)*(log2(N))

```
we need sum of k*log2(k) k from 1 to N
```

Comment: Why from 1 to N? Maybe from 2 to N... This code does not sort sequence, in which one element.

Comment: I have considered N to be storage.size()
So first 0...N (NlogN) then 1...N((N-1)log(N-1) till N-1 to N which is 1log1 (some constant as constanst are also there which are not expressed in this answer)
so from k=1 to N

Comment: "N-1 to N which is 1log1" Please, be carefully, this code does not sort sequence from N-1 to N. for(int i = 0; i < Storage.size() - 1; ++i){...}, then i = N-1, cycle does not start. Last sorting -> then i = N-2, where N - storage.size()

Comment: ya you are correct from 2 to N

but still time complexity in terms of asymptotic notation will remain same